# Вывод из массива по одному элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив, как из него выводить значения по одному, при клике?

Comment: Код покажите, чтобы ответ услышать. Вариантов масса.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
const arr = ['Ваш', 'вопрос','слишком','общий'];
window.onclick = e => console.log(arr.shift());
```